# Modify a binary and account for relative jumps

Tags: binary, x86, reverse-engineering

Most binaries have jump and control flow instructions that are relative to other locations in the binary. For example: if I modify an instruction around `0x12341232`, and there is an instruction somewhere in the code that would do `jmp 0x12341234`, that `0x12341234` location will not be the same.

So,

```
# Original
0x12341232:  mov eax, ebx
0x12341234:  call sym.hello
...

0x13371337:  jmp 0x12341234 # points to correct instruction

--------

# Modified
0x12341232:  call 0x3232
0x12341237:  call sym.hello
...

0x13371337:  jmp 0x12341234 # points to incorrect instruction
```

AFAIK, ARM's ISA would have a lot less trouble handling this issue since it has fixed-length instructions. x86 would have a big issue with this.

My question is: Is there a framework or research paper that tackles this issue?

Many thanks

Comment: Nobody will allow you to modify running code. What do you actually want to achieve?

Comment: Hey!

1. I'm trying to modify a binary on-disk, not in memory for purposes of simplifying a compiled binary by replacing patterns with simplified ones.
2. I think it is possible to modify memory pages and the mapped process sections if you own a piece of the process.

Comment: FYI, would be cool to know why the downvotes... I can rephrase the question better...

Comment: The best way is to get the source code, make your modification, and recompile it. Changing code after it's been compiled is usually nontrivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest would be to conserve all addresses, not shifting code around.

- If the replacing patch is in equal size there is no problem.
- If the patch is smaller you can padd with no-ops, no-operations.
- If the patch is larger, you can add the patch at the end, and insert a jump to it,
  with at the end of the patch a jump back.

In reality there are relative and absolute, short and long jumps. Shifting code around would also take into account the data segments, not to taken as code.

As a binary is the result of linking object files, the code is not that spaghetti like w.r.t. jump/call addresses, but the effort is too large IMHO.

The research you wanted: maybe rather look into *disassemblers*, which might provide generating labels, hence immediately assemblable.

Comment: Thank you, Mr. Eggen!
The idea I had was to have a scanner for all conditional control flows which would work before and after a patch and account for the differences. I do really like the idea of a jump table (point three you mentioned). Many thanks again